# .NET Strategy and shared repositories

Tags: c#, .net, git, nuget

I am working with C# and GIT. I have multiple projects that use shared repositories.
I have Project A, Project B, Project C. I have shared repositories Shared 1, Shared 2. Project A uses Shared 1 and 2. Project B uses Shared 2 and Project C uses Shared 1.

What is a correct approach for referencing Shared repos. Having them directly as source code references or pack them into nuget and use them as a nuget references on each project.
I find it difficult to work concurrently on two projects that use the same shared repository and each one needs changes based on the project they are being used. How do I overcome this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Local NuGets, so you can even have versioning

Comment: Can you explain please what do you mean ?

Answer (score 0):

Nuget is the way to go.
But you could have a look to paket that simplify the use of nuget packages :
https://fsprojects.github.io/Paket/

And especially 2 things that can help you:

- paket local https://fsprojects.github.io/Paket/local-file.html
- git dependencies https://fsprojects.github.io/Paket/git-dependencies.html

Comment: So for every change I do in a shared repository during development of a feature I will have to create a nuget package?

Comment: Yes that's the fate of every developer! Except if you go monorepository with all your projects in the same repository. The 2 solutions have advantages and disadvantages... Or use git submodules (but I don't advise this solution)

Comment: for each commit in a shared repo even if the feature is not yet finished I have to publish to nuget. That sounds redundant :)

Comment: No, if the feature is not yet finished, either copy the dlls or use nuget /paket local to test. Once it's finished, then publish and use it.

Comment: What is local nuget?

Comment: ok but lets say in a scenario that I release my app (Project A) which uses Shared 2 v1.0.0. After a month Shared Repo is version 1.2.0. Project A still uses Shared Repo 1.0.0 on production and a bug was found in this version of Shared Repo (1.0.0). How can I debug it in this case and find the bug?

Comment: Hello @pantonis and others,
any news about a solution to work with multi repo and nuget ?