# Working with Multiple Nuget Projects in one Solution

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-2017

I have 2 projects: `A` & `B` that I want to publish as NuGet Packages but I don't know how to **develop efficiently** in Visual Studio.

```
Solution 1
   Project A
   Project B - references Project A as NuGet reference
```

When I make a change to `Project A` that is needed in `Project B` do I have to publish `Project A`?  Is there a way to get the project reference functionality during development?  Maybe `Project B` shouldn't reference `Project A` via NuGet?

There must be a good way to handle this situation, no?  I've reviewed the [NuGet docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/what-is-nuget) but I couldn't find anything.  There must be docs/blogs/SO posts to read more about this... I'm struggling to come up w/ the right keywords.

Comment: what about this issue? Would you please let me know the latest information about this issue? if below answer resolved your question, you could mark it as the answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issues.

Comment: Hi @LeoLiu-MSFT - I've upvoted as the info helped.  I'm kinda torn here.  I don't know that any one of them is the answer.  I feel like they could be combined into one answer w/ multiple solutions.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to look at this extension: [NuGet Reference Switcher for Visual Studio 2017](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=RicoSuter.NuGetReferenceSwitcherforVisualStudio2017)

This allows you to switch between NuGet packages and project references during development.

Answer (score 3):

Check out this blog post: https://markheath.net/post/multiple-nuget-single-repo

Basically, `dotnet pack` handles this for you automatically. You use regular project references when developing.

Answer (score 2):

> There must be a good way to handle this situation, no?

The best solutions is that **the project-to-project reference should be recommend when the referenced project is modified frequently**, **the nuget reference is more appropriate when share the reference project to others or publish it**. Just like [NuGet Reference Switcher](https://github.com/rsuter/NuGetReferenceSwitcher) doing.

For some more detailed info, you can check following thread:

[nuget packages in local work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42928415/nuget-packages-in-local-work/42945083#42945083)

> NuGet has many advantages as a package manager for the Microsoft
> development platform, this does not mean that it is not flawed. Just
> as you encountered, if the referenced project is modified frequently,
> we have to rebuild it, build nuget, publish it for each modification.
> That will bring a lot of boring work. To resolve this disadvantages,
> the Project-to-project references should be a better way.
>
> The
> advantage of a project-to-project reference is that it creates a
> dependency between the projects in the build system. The dependent
> project will be built if it has changed since the last time the
> referencing project was built. A file reference does not create a
> build dependency, so it is possible to build the referencing project
> without building the dependent project.

Answer (score 1):

You could add following Post-build event command to pack your project after building.

```
"the nuget.exe path\nuget.exe" pack "project path\NuGetPackageLibrary.csproj" -OutputDirectory "Your target path"
```

When your build successful, the package in target path will be replaced by the latest version.